# How to stop my trailing line causing object to slow down due to size of array

Tags: javascript, arrays, canvas

My square object on the canvas slows down drastically as the array gets larger. The array is used to store previous x,y locations and then the trailing line uses these locations to draw itself.

Is there a way to have my object move at the same speed while keeping the entire trailing line i.e i don't want the trailing line fading/disappearing at any point in time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<style>
canvas {
    border:1px solid #d3d3d3;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>

var myGamePiece;
var myArrayX = [];
var myArrayY = [];

function startGame() {
    myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
    myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 480;
        this.canvas.height = 270;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    },
    clear : function() {
        this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    }
    }




function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.speedX = 0;
    this.speedY = 0;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;    
    this.update = function() {
        ctx = myGameArea.context;
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);

         // testing:
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.setLineDash([5,5]);
    ctx.moveTo(10, 120);
    var arrLength = myArrayX.length;
    for(var i=0; i<arrLength;i+=1){
    ctx.lineTo(myArrayX[i], myArrayY[i]);
    ctx.stroke();
    }

    }
    this.newPos = function() {
        this.x += this.speedX;
        this.y += this.speedY;  
        myArrayX.push(this.x);
        myArrayY.push(this.y);
    }   
    //end test
}

function updateGameArea() {
    myGameArea.clear();
    myGamePiece.newPos();    
    myGamePiece.update();
    document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "size of array: " + (myArrayX.length -1).toString()

}



window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode){
    case 37:
        myGamePiece.speedX = -1;
        break;
    case 38:
        myGamePiece.speedY = -1; 
        break;
    case 39:
        myGamePiece.speedX = 1;
        break;
    case 40:
        myGamePiece.speedY = 1;
        break;
    }
})

window.onkeyup = function() {
    switch(window.event.keyCode){
    case 37:
        myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
        break;
    case 38:
        myGamePiece.speedY = 0; 
        break;
    case 39:
        myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
        break;
    case 40:
        myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
        break;
    }
}
</script>

<p id="test"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Interest staff I will put myGamePiece.newPos(); like update func . Also your 'update' is draw method in real.  Just rename it. AN one this.newPos remove from component and make it with passing args. They you can use this.newPos = function(x, y) for any other component.

Comment: Avoid 'setInterval' it is not best praticle. Better make it like self calling function or use requestAnimationFrame.

Comment: requestAnimationFrame over setInterval will be the best optimalisation. You can also debounce the keydown event since it sets speedX and Y to fixed values, so it does not matter how long the key is held down each frame, only if if was down or not during that frame. You can probably also gain a few ms by not using global variables, but passing everything around as parameters, so you have less scope lookups to find the variables. The best optimalisation would obviously be to not redraw everything every time, but just keep drawing from where you ended the previous frame.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Anatomy Interesting read discussing the requestAnimationFrame in the context of rendering a game, which is very similar to this.

Answer (score 2):

There's a rewarding optimization you can do. At the moment you're adding numbers to both myArrayX and myArrayY with each update. That means if you're square doesn't move at all, you will have a lot of useless data since the position didn't change.

I'd recommend: just put elements to the array if either the x or the y position has changed. This can be done by setting up two global variables which hold the last x and y coordinate and compare to these before updating the arrays.

Take a look at this:

```js
var myGamePiece;
var myArrayX = [];
var myArrayY = [];
var oldX = 0;
var oldY = 0;

function startGame() {
  myGamePiece = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
  myGameArea.start();
}

var myGameArea = {
  canvas: document.createElement("canvas"),
  start: function() {
    this.canvas.width = 480;
    this.canvas.height = 270;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
  },
  clear: function() {
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}




function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.update = function() {
    ctx = myGameArea.context;
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);

    // testing:
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.setLineDash([5, 5]);
    ctx.moveTo(10, 120);
    var arrLength = myArrayX.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < arrLength; i += 1) {
      ctx.lineTo(myArrayX[i], myArrayY[i]);
      ctx.stroke();
    }

  }
  this.newPos = function() {

    this.x += this.speedX;
    this.y += this.speedY;

    if (this.x != oldX || this.y != oldY) {
      myArrayX.push(this.x);
      myArrayY.push(this.y);
    }


    oldX = this.x;
    oldY = this.y;

  }
  //end test
}

function updateGameArea() {
  myGameArea.clear();
  myGamePiece.newPos();
  myGamePiece.update();
  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = "size of array: " + (myArrayX.length - 1).toString()

}



window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      myGamePiece.speedX = -1;
      break;
    case 38:
      myGamePiece.speedY = -1;
      break;
    case 39:
      myGamePiece.speedX = 1;
      break;
    case 40:
      myGamePiece.speedY = 1;
      break;
  }
})

window.onkeyup = function() {
  switch (window.event.keyCode) {
    case 37:
      myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
      break;
    case 38:
      myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
      break;
    case 39:
      myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
      break;
    case 40:
      myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
      break;
  }
}
startGame();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
```

```html
<p id="test"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your algorithm to store the coordinates of the traversed line each time you change direction instead of storing each step - see https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2XRK.png

You array in above example will contain 18 elements instead of 1086.